# Best method to add data.frame data to an outputted list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a main data frame which I want to extract data from:

```
position = c(1:20)
transfer_budget = seq(100, 10, length.out=20)

df = data.frame(position, transfer_budget)
rownames(df) = c("CHE","TOT","MCY","LIV", "MUN", "ARS", "EVE", "WBA", "STK", "SOU", "BOU", "WHM", "BUR", "WAT", "LEI", "CRY", "SWA", "HUL", "MID", "SUN")
```

I have created a rather complicated code that categorises certain football teams into groups and the output is as a list.

```
my_list = list()
my_list[[1]] = c("MUN","MCY","CHE","ARS","LIV")
my_list[[2]] = c("BUR","SOU","BOU","STK","ARS")
my_list[[3]] = c("EVE","SUN","SWA","HUL","LEI")
my_list[[4]] = c("MCY","LIV","CHE","WBA")
my_list[[5]] = c("LEI","TOT","BOU")
```

I want to expand on the output as add additional data, however I'm not sure the most effective way to do this?  How would I add the position and transfer_budget to my_list?

Currently I have the team names as row names, is it better to have them as a column instead in the data frame?  My initial idea would be to convert the output list to a transposed matrix and then match the values then cbind but I don't want to get into bad habits.

Comment: Is there any pattern by which you are grouping as each `list` element

Comment: Not particularly, I should have noted that my lists are also different lengths in my model.

Comment: I guess you wanted the matching elements for position and transfer_budget to be added, right?

Comment: Yep! I actually have more data but didn't feel the need to add it above.

Comment: `lapply(my_list, function(x) df[match(x, row.names(df)), c("position", "transfer_budget")])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do by looping over the `list`, `match` with the rownames of dataset 'df' and create `data.frame`

```
my_list1 <- lapply(my_list, function(x) {
           `row.names<-`(transform(df[match(x, row.names(df)),], teamNames = x), NULL)})
my_list1[[1]]
#   position transfer_budget teamNames
#1        5        81.05263       MUN
#2        3        90.52632       MCY
#3        1       100.00000       CHE
#4        6        76.31579       ARS
#5        4        85.78947       LIV
```

Comment: Beginner question, but how would you put team names as the first column?

Comment: @Aesler  You can do a `cbind` i.e. `lapply(my_list, function(x) {cbind(TeamNames = x, df[match(x, row.names(df)),])})`